# Overflow into sanitized water.

Tags: fermentation

Hello fellow home brewers, I recently brewed my first Belgian stout and used a liquid yeast for the first time as well. I got my stout into the primary early on Sunday morning, I used a tube going into sanitized water as my blow off. The bubbling from the primary seemed to be going well until I came home early Tuesday morning to find that my beer (and presumably some yeast) had overflowed through the tube and into the sanitized water. So my question is, has anybody had this happen before and why did this happen. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Happens all the time**

Nothing to worry about, other than a mess.

**Couple tips.**

More head space in fermentor can prevent this.

Larger diameter hose is recommended 1/2+ if you think it may happen. Small  diameter hoses can clog and blow off leaving beer exposed without an airlock.

If using starsan in your reservoir harvesting the krausen yeast from it is an easy way to keep a strain. Read up on yeast washing.

When the resevoir gets yeast and wort in it, replace it asap. As it can get diluted and no longer work as sanitizer. But save it!

**As to the why it happened**

Low head space and a good vigorous fermentation.

Comment: Thanks Evil. The space issue does make sense. I have 5.5 gallons in a 6 gallon fermenter.